# MySQL reuse virtual row

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a simple table of:

```
id,name,salary
```

The query I have is:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (salary+1) as MS
FROM test_table
```

The query I would like is:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (salary+1) as MS,
       (MS-20) as MS2
FROM test_table
```

Is that possible in any way or is the only option to make new subquery every time I need to get MS value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use user-defined variables:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  @MS1:=(salary+1) as MS1,
  (@MS1-20) as MS2
FROM test_table;
```

But queries that contain user-defined variables can not be cached by MySQL's Query Cache (in case you care).

Comment: Thanks, this is what i have been looking for.

Comment: cool, now i can faster my query reuse if else, switch case statement with @variable

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (salary+1) as MS,
       ((salary+1)-20) as MS2
FROM test_table
```

Comment: Yes, thats my point, i have to rewrite (salary+1) instead of using just MS.